# I don't want to show my webviews url in Android apps when users wifi is off

Tags: java, android, webview

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.blackboy.allchannellive;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

   // private AdView mAdView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        // for web view
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        String url = "http://shafayetice1.blogspot.com/";
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());


    }


    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.i("WEB_VIEW_TEST", "error code:" + errorCode);
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

        }
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        webView.onPause();
    }




    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        webView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }



}
```

> please help me.how can I do it if no internet
>     just show internet is not available.please check your WiFi is on or off
>   just this massage
>
> ### when net is off just show now web page is not available
>
> url is http://shafayetice1.blogspot.com............. ##
>   but I don't want to show it.

Comment: Add TextView in your activity_main.xml and check if internet is not available hide webview and make textview visible with your desire message.

Answer (score 0):

Add following permissions in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
```

Then in your activity add following code

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
//do you work , show your webviews url.
 }else{
 //  Show your error message. 
}
```

Comment: its not work  if (wifi.isWifiEnabled()) show error here

Comment: it show error  (isWifiEnabled) in this line say need api

Answer (score 0):

You want to check network connectivity status before you load the url in webview. this link will help you to implement that feature in you app.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/

Answer (score 0):

First of all create two views in your activity_main.xml.
1. WebView (Initially visible)
2. No Internet Connection View with sad image or any thing else (Initially visibility gone).

Now before loading webview first of all check internet connection

```
if(internetConnection){
  setWebViewVisibility VISIBLE
 setNointernetConnectionView GONE
  loadWebView();
}else{
 setWebViewVisibility GONE
 setNointernetConnectionView VISIBLE
}
```